# Is there any way to generate JPA Entities correctly of several schemas?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, entity, joincolumn

I have a big database divided in several schemas. From eclipse wizard (JPA Tools) I generate the JPA Entities of one schema, but there are some tables with dependencies on other tables in other schemas, and the problem is that those entities are created like this:

```
//Foreign Key of one table in other schema
@Column(name="TABLE_ID")
private BigDecimal tableId;
```

And I think it must be generated this way:

```
//Foreign Key of one table in other schema
@JoinColum(name="TABLE_ID")
private TableClass tableId;
```

Is the second way more correct than first one? Is there any way to generate automatically the JPA Entities in the second way??

Comment: Whats happening seems to be correct.  tableId is a column of some table.   you would expect it to be something like a long, int, decimal or similar.  The only Class that an id would map to would be a PK class in the case of a composite key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ids are generated instead of actual entity relationships when there is no visibility to the **TableClass** from the jdbc connection.. creating public synonyms (or equivalent) to these tables might help.  This kind of behaviour can be observed with reverse engineering even when tables are chosen selectively. entity realationships to unselected tables would typically be generated in the fashion that you are currently experiencing

for e.g. for there are two tables Person and Address and a link from Address to Person..

selecting both Person and Address would generate a proper entity relatioship in Address like

```
private Person person;
```

On the other hand, selecting just Address will simply create a mapping to the raw type as the Person entity is not generated by JPA Tools

```
private BigDecimal personId;
```

which is what seems to be happening in your case

`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is happening, but when I click on `JPA Tools > Generate Entities from Tables` I only can choose one schema. The real question is if there is any way to select all schemas to generate the Entities with `private Person person;`. Thanks.

Comment: if this is oracle, you can expose A.TableA and B.TableB through A's connection by creating a public synonym of B.TableB in schema A.  The reverse engineering tool would then see B.TableB as A.TableB

Comment: The problem is that I can't modfify the DB

Comment: you may want to experiment with either appfuse or spring roo.  spring roo has incremental reverse engineering.  btw, if your child table is not accessible from the parent database connection how do you plan to persist both entities as part of the same hibernate session.  i guess you would need two connection factories.